# What is a good data structure for drawing a recursive graph?

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

I need a data structure that will allow me to draw the objects in a very specific way.
When I drop an element above or below another element on a canvas, a line is drawn between the two.

[image]

When I drop an element to the left or right on a canvas, a square box is formed with the two elements completing the square in the diagram below.

[image]

This can go on theoretically infinitely with the structures connecting like this.

[image]

My requirements state that each time an element is dropped (blue boxes) the structures should draw from the inner most element recursively until the entire connected structure is redrawn.
I’ve tried implementing this with a graph using an adjacency list but that didn’t seem to work. Perhaps I implemented it wrong.

I’ve recently tried my own data structure, but this is not working as expected:

```
export class Structure {
  id!: string;
  type!: StructureType; // type of structure I want to draw
  childStructures: Structure[] = [];
  elements: BaseElement[] = [];
}
```

In the above code, my thought process is that each drawing is treated as a structure and each can have child structures of different types within them. The elements represent the blue squares. The structure will have to redraw from this data structure that will be converted to JSON. I’ve been at this awhile now trying to come up with the perfect data structure complete this task and am falling short. If anyone can add some clarity, it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is the newly dropped element exactly parallel to an existing one? For example, if we already have a square named A, can we drop another square at top-left position of A?

Comment: @blaz yes, it can be dropped parallel to the other. I have already figured out how to draw these individually, but the person leading the project didn't like my implementation. They want it to always be drawn from the 'internal representation' of the graph, which will be one master data structure that will allow drawing of all scenarios as they drop on the page in real time.